# Is it possible for 3 teams to tie with 3 wins and 1 loss each in a 5 team round robin tournament?

Tags: probability

5 team round robin tournament, is it possible for 3 teams to tie with 3 wins and 1 loss each?Is this mathematically possible?

Comment: Have you tried anything?

Comment: Any thoughts on the answer I posted yesterday, Carla?

Comment: It's not polite, Carla, to ask for help, and then ignore the help you get.

Answer (score 1):

$$
\matrix{-&1&0&1&1\cr0&-&1&1&1\cr1&0&-&1&1\cr0&0&0&-&1\cr0&0&0&0&-\cr}
$$